# Can't locate element - Selenium

Tags: python, facebook, parsing, selenium

I'm trying to find a textarea in my facebook group. The login is ok, `driver.get(group)` is ok too but then, when I try to locate the textarea, it returns that it can't locate it. The weird thing is that I can clearly see it there.

```
  def send_post(self,text,group):
        assert self.logged == True
        self.driver.get(group)
        text_field = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.innerWrap').find_element_by_tag_name('xhpc_message_text')
        text_field.send_keys(text)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@value='1']").click()
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong? Do you have a better way to post to fb group?

Comment: Your `text_field = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.innerWrap').find_element_by_tag_name('xhpc_message_text')` looks a little strange to me (you're finding an element then finding an element). Is there a particular reason why you're doing that? Have you tried only using the `find_element_by_tag_name('xhpc_message_text')` or possible finding it by its class name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xhpc_message_text` isn't a tag name; `textarea` is.

If you're talking about the post-writing `<textarea>`, then it has a `name` attribute (different!) of `xhpc_message_text`. You can combine your `find_element_by_*` calls into one:

```
text_field = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.innerWrap [name="xhpc_message_text"]')
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But I can't click a submit button. I had a suspection that I can't locate it properly so I've copied the xpath using chrome. It act's like it clicked on that button but no post can be seen there.

Comment: Glad this helped. Your submit-button issue probably warrants a separate question, but you might try `text_field.submit()` first as an alternative to your button click, per [these docs' guidance](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html#filling-in-forms). (If that doesn't work, though, I'd definitely suggest posting it as a new question.)